# Won't apply style until refresh HTML

Tags: css, html

I have index.html and guide.html, I link to the guide.html in the index page. however when i go to the guide one through the link the page won't have the design until I refresh. What am I doint wrong? Each page has its own css.

Here's an image right after I click:
[image]

And here's another one right after I refresh:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your cache?

Comment: It would **NOT** be possible to solve your problem without code. Maybe you could reproduce the problem in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned the cache, still no.

Answer (score 0):

Could be cached css/html. If it looks right after pressing ctrl+F5 on the page in question, it is working correctly.

Comment: It does look ok after any kind of refresh, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers cache CSS files. I see you're using Chrome for Windows - <kbd>CTRL + F5</kbd> will fully refresh the page, CSS and all.

If this problem appears on a live site for some reason, you could re-name your CSS file to avoid the browser using a cached version. For instance `custom.css` would become `custom-2.css`.

Comment: The CSS files already have different namess. I've used CTRL+F5 and no luck. Works the same way. I'm running it in the phonegap app as well and I face the same problem.

Comment: @AndreiLorincz Why does each page have its own CSS? It is generally a good idea to have one CSS file.

Comment: For no reason, shouldnt fail though. I'll try to use only one. I'll update here to let you know.